# How does one inject resources into an already built executable

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I am working on a windows application that will need to be branded. The client will be selling this to other businesses, and needs a customized logo and name for each sale.

The client does not know how to use visual studio!

I think I need to write a packager app to inject custom logo and string resources into the executable. I am planning on using WPF. But since this is a critical requirement, I'd be willing to do it in winforms if that is easier.

What is the best way to do this? Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: You can't specify that the images and names be loaded from an external file at run-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you are after is application skinning. This doesn't mean you have to unpack the exe and inject resources. You just need to consider skinning from the start of the project and build the application to support your skinning requirements.

WPF will make skinning your app much easier. There will be several different ways to accomplish what you want.

Simplest is to leave the logo image loose and reference it with a relative path from the XAML file(s) that need to show this image.

You should look into Resource Dictionaries in WPF and how they help you group resources and support skinning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx

The text will be a little different but I am not sure what you need as far as a text goes. Do you mean you need to localize the strings or do you simply need different text (all the same locale) to show for different clients?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution (perhaps not the simplest one) is to use a parent application which compiles source code for generating child application. You can do it with [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) and [CompilerParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx) classes. Add the image as an embedded resource and retrieve it in the child application. A working demo with a source code is available at [Slide Show Builder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SlideShowBuilder.aspx#Buildingtheslideshow8).

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion for the exact question you asked (although I suspect there is another way by reconsidering the exact requirements) would be to write a utility which uses ildasm to disassemble the assembly, then use ilasm to reassemble it and include your new resource file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution is to provide the bitmap along with the EXE as a separate file.  Actually replacing an embedded resource in the EXE requires decompiling it with `ildasm.exe` and putting it back together with `ilasm.exe`.  `Ildasm.exe` is only available in the Windows SDK, it can be downloaded separately.  Error prone and small odds that your customer can get that right, you'll need to provide them with, say, a .bat file that does this.

Of course, whomever is interested in replacing the logo, for whatever reason, would not be slowed down by replacing either the separate image file *or* using the `Ildasm.exe` trick.  There is therefore very little point in making it any more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: Why not just write a little C# app that calls the compiler, that is there regardless of the SDK (comes with runtime).