# How to inject a text resource into a prebuilt native EXE?

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource, native-code

I have a native EXE (namely a setup.exe type of file).  I'd like to inject into it a text resource, e.g. Server=X123456.

The purpose is that upon running the EXE, it would read the text resource and act accordingly.  Is there a way to do this from C# code?

Note that there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962472/how-does-one-inject-resources-into-an-already-built-executable), but it focused on injecting skins into a WPF app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has an API for updating resources in native executables. Check out the documentation for [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends.